# Feeds not expiring records after update to alpha9

Tags: feeds

I run 3 Feeds multiple times daily.  Has worked Flawlessly for years.  When I updated using composer I now noticed that when importing, the 'Expiring' process never happens.  of the 469 records all are from before August 2020.  Normally the number of records expired would show up as well.
So maybe should I use composer to go back to Alpha7?
[image: results of importing]

---

The log shows
[image: log message]

---

The settings are
[image: feed settings]

---

Drupal 8.9.7 using Feeds 8.x-3.0-alpha9

Comment: Sounds like a module bug.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug indeed. The bug is introduced in alpha7 however - I did some refactoring of the import process in there and I happen to have missed a line that was triggering the expire process. The bug is not in alpha6.

Comment: I restored to alpha2 and everything is working again.  I locked it where it is. I am happy

Comment: I created an issue for this :). You might need to update the site to D9 at some point.
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3193092

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is reported as a bug.